# Which model for testing "has this binary variable changed over time?"

Tags: regression, time-series, binary-data, statsmodels

I am trying to figure out if a list of historical documents (N=50) drifted from one value of a binary variable $w$ to the other. Users have given 1 to 5 votes whether they think they think the documents, presented in random order, have this property $w$. To clarify, the question might have been: "Do you think this document is about cats or dogs [c/d]", and the analysis is whether the topic of the documents remained cats, or drifted from cats to dogs over time. We can assume the early documents were about cats.

For each of the votes I have a document identifier which increase over time, and a binary vote.

My intuition tells me a simple regression with the votes as the dependent and the document id as the independent variable should suffice, since the votes are independent and are not ordinal, or temporal. The documents however are, so I have looked at ARIMA and GEE models, but am not sure whether they are appropriate for this case.

---

[edit example in code]

I'm developing this in Python. With Pandas dataframe, in the early stage when there is just one vote per document

```
print(catdocuments[['docid', 'cattyness']].head(3))
   docid  cattyness
0     44       True
1     55      False
2     58       True
```

I can plot

```
figc, axc = plt.subplots()
axc.set_xlim([catdocuments['docid'].min(), catdocuments['docid'].max()])
axc.set_ylim([0, 1])
axc.set_title("Linear regression, n={}".format(len(catdocuments)))
sns.regplot(data=catdocuments, x='docid', y='cattyness', ax=axc);
```

[image: Linear regression of cattyness w over time]

For modeling, I've started with Seaborn's regression plot (above), plus `OLS` and `Logit` from statsmodels, both of which give statistically significant *p*-values for *cattyness ~ docid* at $\alpha = 0.05$, but future data from further voters might not be as clear.

So I am conceptually unsure whether this is sufficient for inference, or I whether I should model with ARIMA, GEE (`statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA` and `statsmodels.genmod.generalized_estimating_equations.GEE` respectively) or some other conceptualization and models.

Comment: Have you plotted the votes vs document id? Maybe the relationship will be sufficiently obvious that no statistical analysis is needed. (I have no idea how to analyse the data beyond that. Sorry.)

Comment: I'm having trouble envisioning the data.  The historical documents are all the same kind of document, but different editions, or years, or something like that?  And the essential difference between one document and another is the year of publication?  And what does it mean "users have given 1 to 5 votes"?  They only vote on 1-5 documents, or they vote on a scale from 1 to 5, or something else?

Comment: @MichaelLew I have some of the data (votes) at this point, have plotted it, and there is a pretty obvious correlation between the ordinal document id, and the binary votes. Based on them, I can (non-statistically) confidently state that the topic has drifted towards dogs. But this is with just one voter, exactly for developing the process. The plan is to have other voters contribute once I have this figured out, since the voting system gives them intermediary results once they have given a number of votes

Comment: @TheLaconic The documents are unique. Each of them has some message which we can interpret to be either about cats or dogs. In addition each of them has an id, which is an increasing number and can thus be used to order the documents in time. Each of the voters were (rather: will be) shown a subset (n=20) of the documents one by one, with replacement, and for each of the shown documents are asked to tell whether the topic of the document has the property w or not. That's why each of the documents has at least one, but probably several votes.